# Contador regressivo não para em Zero

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Cronometro regressivo não para quando chega a "0".
Preciso que o cronometro pare quando chegar a "0" e ao clicar no botão "iniciar" o mesmo comece com o valor setado, que é "1 min" e decremente ate "0" novamente. Os Botões de parar e Somar 1 min estão funcionando.

Abaixo segue códigos dos botões:

```
    this.iniciarCronometro = this.iniciarCronometro.bind(this);
    this.pararCronometro = this.pararCronometro.bind(this);
    this.tempoFormatado = this.tempoFormatado.bind(this);
    this.somarUmSegundo = this.somarUmSegundo.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      contadorSegundo: 0,
      contadorMinuto: 1,
    };
  }

  iniciarCronometro() {
    var intervalId = setInterval(this.somarUmSegundo, 100);
    this.setState({
      intervalId: intervalId,
    });
  }

  pararCronometro() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    this.setState({
      contadorSegundo: 0,
      contadorMinuto: 1,
    });
  }

  somarUmMinuto() {
    this.setState({
      contadorMinuto: this.state.contadorMinuto + 1,
    });
  }
```

O Código abaixo faz o cronometro funcionar. A forma como ele esta implementado o contador não para quando chega a "0". Preciso que pare quando zerar e quando eu chamar a função iniciar ele comece do valor setado " 1".

```
somarUmSegundo() {
    let segundos = this.state.contadorSegundo;
    let minutos = this.state.contadorMinuto;

    minutos == 1 || segundos > 0;
    if (segundos == 0) {
      segundos = 59;
      minutos = minutos - 1;
    } else {
      segundos = segundos - 1;
    }

    this.setState({
      contadorSegundo: segundos,
      contadorMinuto: minutos,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara, tem como apontar mais detalhes?

Comment: @Francisco atualizei o código e coloquei mais informações.

Comment: Cara, agora tem informações demais kk. Se possivel estruture a pergunta seguindo o modelo de [mcve].

Comment: @Francisco atualizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua função `somarUmSegundo()` não faz muito sentido. Tente desta forma:

```
somarUmSegundo() {
    if (this.state.contadorSegundo == 0) {
        if (this.state.contadorMinuto > 0) {
            this.setState(antigo => ({
                contadorMinuto: antigo.contadorMinuto - 1
                contadorSegundo: 59
            }));
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
            return;
        }
    }

    this.setState(antigo => ({
        contadorSegundo: antigo.contadorSegundo - 1
    }));
}
```

Comment: O Código funcionou perfeitamente. Porém quando finaliza a contagem o valor ja retorna para "01:00 min" automaticamente. Preciso que ele fique zerado, só após clicar no button iniciar ele comece a decrementar a partir de "01:00 min". Tentei modificar seu código aqui mas estou com dificuldades.

Comment: Editei a resposta, tenta agr @Philipe